# Very high CPU usage with no active queries

Tags: mysql, windows, cpu, cpu-usage

we run MySQL 5.5 on Windows machines (Dual Core, 12GB RAM).
On one of them, CPU usage is at 50% without a single query being executed. The other one has 0-1% CPU load. 
I think the problem came up in the beginning of july, so I came across some posts regarding a leap second bug:
[MySQL high CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282232/mysql-high-cpu-usage/11293475#11293475) and 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20225/high-cpu-usage-from-mysql-with-no-queries-at-all-running

But the problem seems to be related to the Linux kernel only. Has anyone got an idea where the CPU load could come from?

I have already restarted the server and used my.ini from the server that does not have the high CPU usage. The result is always the same: As soon as MySQL starts, it jumps up to 50% CPU usage.

Thanks for your help, 
klib

Comment: No one? Not even a suggestion? Too bad

Comment: start task manager ( taskmgr.exe ) which will allow you to easy see which processes that are using the cpu.

Comment: 90hex, thanks for the reply. Well mysql.exe is using the CPU. I already mentioned that in my question. Don't know what new information to get from the task manager

Comment: try a) stopping windows time service ( as of your articles )b) check mysql memory settings ( in config  ) c) how much free memory is there? d) have you performed a chkdsk recently?

Comment: 90hex, I have reinstalled the whole machine a few months ago (could not wait any longer for a solution). But I didn't want to close the question since it might be useful for someone else. a) Not reproducible anymore b) Memory settings were exactly the same on both machines c) Not less than 3GB available memory d) CHKDSK was not performed. It is a virtual server on RAID5, so it would have a myjor impact on all the servers running on the same hardware.