# mysql causing high cpu usage

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server

Please see image attached.

Our font-end websites are running super super slow almost to a point where nothing moves for 15-30 minutes.

1. is that because of whatever this mysql thing is is causing the
   high CPU load?
2. how do I stop it? I tried sending a SIGKILL to it
   but that doesent work either. I tried restarting apache/mysql too.
   The process pops up again.

[image]

Comment: Check related thread. Maybe will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282232/mysql-high-cpu-usage?rq=1

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server tech support.

Comment: I did look at that. I dont see any processes. I am looking at the processes in WHM and dont see any process there. If processes show up, they disappear after a second or two which means the process is running pretty fast.

Comment: This sounds like a problem with the OS.  If so, and if it's on Unix, try http://unix.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: I suggest moving this question to serverfault.com, a sister site to stackoverflow. It appears the OP is running the webserver and mysql database on the same server.  Typically, you want them to run on different servers. Then there's the question of WHY is `mysqld` eating nearly half the CPU time. The server admins on serverfault should be able to assist better than a bunch of programmers.

Comment: improve the performance creating primary keys in your tables, or using views, i've had the same problem and i've solved it doing that.

Answer (score -1):

1. Thats probably the reason yes. I dont know what your usual usage is but 40% only for the mysql server is alot.
   Maybe take a look at your logfiles and see if u can find anything there
2. Do you have shell access to the Server this is running on?

If so try to kill it manually over the console.
What system is this service running on?
The last resort would be to restart the server...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHi0M.png..........
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbkrN.png...........
https://i.stack.imgur.com/I89kR.png...........Please see these.

Comment: I can't really tell anything from these pictures... Do you have the mysql logfile? If there are any errors you should be looking there...

Comment: If i kill the process using ssh, it comes back with a new PID.

Comment: I do have the error log, I dont know how to show you that here.

Comment: What operating system is your service running on? Never tried it but maybe you can upload it [link](http://textuploader.com/)

Comment: centos-6-x86_64

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/pj6cggsy5/
-
This is a screenshot of the sql file that has the PID of the mysql query takin up so much CPU. But I dont understand the errors or see anything bad?